# Android App crashes on starting new activity when there is background image

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I have created an android app which is a basic calculator. If i input a certain number a new activity starts. The problem i am facing is that if i have background image in that activity the app crashes but if there isnt then it doesnt.

```js
Main activity, from here if i input that number the new activity starts.

editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String message = (editText.getText().toString());
                if (message.equals("123")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondAct.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }
        });
```

activity_secondact.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SecondAct"
    tools:ignore="Deprecated"
    android:background="@drawable/createdby">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt2"
        android:layout_width="225dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_x="117dp"
        android:layout_y="424dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</LinearLayout>
```

```html
11-02 22:57:20.204 5499-5499/com.example.tanmaycalculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tanmaycalculator, PID: 5499
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tanmaycalculator/com.example.tanmaycalculator.SecondAct}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2487)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2547)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:543)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.example.tanmaycalculator.SecondAct.onCreate(SecondAct.java:14)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6355)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2440)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2547) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:649)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:698)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:766)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:496)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170) 
        at com.example.tanmaycalculator.SecondAct.onCreate(SecondAct.java:14) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6355) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2440) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2547) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:623)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:698) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:766) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:496) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170) 
        at com.example.tanmaycalculator.SecondAct.onCreate(SecondAct.java:14) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6355) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2440) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2547) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.tanmaycalculator:drawable/createdby" (7f070067) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f070067 a=-1 r=0x7f070067}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2646)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2580)
        at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:398)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:872)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3963)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:574)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:203)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:199)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:195)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:623) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:698) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:766) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:496) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170) 
        at com.example.tanmaycalculator.SecondAct.onCreate(SecondAct.java:14) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6355) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2440) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2547) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
```

SecondAct

```js
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SecondAct extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondact);
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt2);
    }
    EditText editText;
}
```

Comment: there is inflation issue at the second activity, please share its code

Comment: check if @drawable/createdby is present in drawable folder or not

Comment: its there @Gautam